# Writing DataRows into multiple CSV files

Tags: vb.net

I am using the following code to create a CSV from a collection of DataRows:

```
      Dim filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv" 'assign a temp file
        Using csvWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, True)

            'write column headings
            csvWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", "AcctNumber", "AccountHolderName", "AccountOption", "Address1", "Address2", "City", "State", "Zip"))

            For Each row in LetterRows 'collection of datarows
                csvWriter.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}", row.AcctNumber, row.AcctHolderName, row.AccountOption, row.Address1, row.Address2, row.City, row.ST, row.ZIP))
            Next row

        End Using
```

This correctly writes all the datarows out to the CSV.  I now want to put an upper limit, say 5000, and create a new csv each time I have written ~5000 records (I will maintain each file in a list of string).  I was thinking along the lines of this:

```
 Dim filesCreated As New List(Of String)
 Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv" 'assign a temp file
    filesCreated.Add(filename)

    For i = 0 To LetterRows.Count - 1

        Using csv As New System.IO.StreamWriter(filename, True) 'dont think this is efficient, what to do

            'write data here


        End Using

        If i Mod 5000 = 0 Then
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv" 'assign a temp file
            filesCreated.Add(filename)
        End If
    Next i
```

I think that is kind of sloppy however and I do not think the using loop in this context makes much sense because I am opening and closing the writer for each record.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do instead is put all the rows into a string and write the entire string at one time. This might be a bit better instead of initializing the writer every line?

```
 Dim to_write as String 

 For i = 0 To LetterRows.Count - 1

   to_write = to_write & vbCrLf & 'newline 

   if i = 5000 Then
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,to_write)   
      filename = 'increment or set your new/next filename here
      to_write = ""   'reset string and continue 
   End if

 Next
```

So the string will store all your data until it is ready to write. The vbCrLf will make sure each line is separated.